# Upgrading OpenGL

Tags: mesa

My graphics are Intel® Q45/Q43 and my processor is Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93GHz × 2. I have the latest mesa: 11.3.0 but my OpenGL version string is still 2.1. Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obvious. This adapter does not support OpenGL 3.x.

Your adapter supports OpenGL up to 2.1.

Reference: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005524.html?_ga=1.180734242.406617348.1451922284